# algebraic data type field name not recognised

Tags: haskell

I have a declaration of an algebraic data type
in one module and use this data structure in another.

In `Convert.hs` I have

```
module Convert (makeTables, Table) where

data Table = Table {
    headers :: [[String]],
    datarows :: [[String]]
    }
    deriving (Show)  
-- ...
```

In another module I have:

```
import Convert

titles :: Table -> [String]
titles t = map (intercalate " ") (headers t)
```

The compiler apparently is aware of `Table` as it does pass the function signature. However, `headers` field name is not available:

```
    Variable not in scope: headers :: Table -> [[[Char]]]
   |
10 | titles t = map (intercalate " ") (headers t)
   |                                   ^^^^^^^
```

Any remedies possible to this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to export the fields of the data type:

```
module Convert (makeTables, Table(..)) where
--                               ~~~~
```

Currently you only export the data type itself, so it’s opaque—the fields are private to the `Convert` module. This is useful if you want a data structure that can only be constructed or manipulated using a certain public API. (E.g. the “smart constructor” pattern.)

Typically if you plan to import `Convert` unqualified, you would prefix the field names so they don’t clash with anything:

```
data Table = Table
  { tableHeaders :: [[String]]
  , tableDataRows :: [[String]]
  } deriving (Show)
```

But you can also leave them as-is and import the module qualified, e.g.:

```
import Convert (Table)
import qualified Convert

titles :: Table -> [String]
titles t = map (intercalate " ") (Convert.headers t)
```

Comment: Special thanks for advice on naming and qualified imports!

Comment: @EPo: My pleasure. :) I prefer qualified imports generally; even though they’re more verbose, they make it clearer where a name comes from when reading unfamiliar code. Also if a dependency adds a new export, an unqualified import can introduce clashes, but a qualified import can’t.